# NSUrl adding selection criteria

Tags: nsurl

I have the following code and I cannot work out from the IOS developer documentation how to add some selection criteria (for the PHP) to the url

My php works when I add /?category=sports but how to I get this added to my kGETUrl string

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `stringWithFormat` to add parameters.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?category=sports", kGETUrl];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

if you want to get sports part from a variable;

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?category=%@", kGETUrl, categorySelected];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Hi, being a bit thick (SDK newbie) what should I do if the 'sports' is actually stored in categorySelected. Thanks

Comment: Edited answer according to your new question. You can give unlimited variables inside stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add to the string:

```
[kGETUrl stringByAppendingString:@"?category=sports"];
```